# Multiple select in pipeline in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the following stage in jenkins where I select the directory to build from a list of directories. After the pipeline runs, it prompts me to select one directory to build.( In a previous step I get the list of all directories to build and save it into a file.) With the ChoiceParameterDefinition I can only select one option when the prompt appears. Now, I want to modify this so that I can select multiple directories in the prompt to build with the job. I was looking into ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition but it only takes a string, unlike the ChoiceParamterDefinition which takes a list of string.

```
 stage('Select directories to build) {
            steps{
                script {
                   env.DIRECTORIES = readFile (file: "directorylist.txt")
                    
                    def userInput = input(
                    id: 'directory', message: 'input parameters', parameters: [
                        [
                            $class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition',
                            name: 'builddir',
                            choices: env.DIRECTORIES,
                            description: 'selection for all DIRECTORY to BUILD',
                        ]
                    ]
                    )
```